# Сделать редирект

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-redirect

Нужно сделать редирект на адрес https://xn----8sbwhcgscfiy8e.xn--p1ai/ , это сайт на WordPress называется. крипто-школа.рф
Вот .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xn----8sbwhcgscfiy8e.xn--p1ai/ [L,R=301]
```

Но этот редирект не работает. Как это сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На хостинге Макхост редирект на другой url делается так

```
Redirect / http://www.site.ru
```